# Is it possible to remotely login to a Mac a la X11?

Tags: mac, remote-desktop

One thing that I like about Linux is that it's (relatively) easy to use a box in more then one people a time, via gdm or kdm. Or, in emergency cases, via ssh -X.

Now I'm using the Mac a lot but I really miss that feature. Yeah, screen sharing is wonderful, but I'd like to remotely *login* into my machine. Is it possible? What about ssh -X?

Comment: Mac has X11, if you want to run X remotely you can.  Is that what you want or do you want to run Aqua remotely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes/no. As freiheit explained yes you can connect using VNC, etc.

However having more than one person logged in use the computer at once? You can't out of the box - at least when it comes to a GUI. You can have multiple people logged in via SSH and such, but something akin to Terminal Server on Windows - not out of the box.

If you want multiple people to log in and use a GUI instance check out [AquaConnect](http://www.aquaconnect.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with VNC or with Apple's (commercial, $$) Apple Remote Desktop product.  With VNC, you probably want to forward the connection over ssh, since it doesn't support encryption.

With OSX 10.4 it's built in.  Under system preferences / Sharing, click "Remote Management" and in there there's a "Computer Management" button that has an option to turn on VNC.  Definitely set a password.  :)  (10.3 and earlier you can find VNC servers)

You'll need a VNC client.  [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) is what's usually recommended on OSX, but there's VNC clients for everything.

I believe the default port is 5900, so you could run "`ssh -L5900:localhost:5900 HOSTNAME`" before starting up the VNC connection.

Actual X11 and `ssh -X` will only help with X11 applications, which you probably don't care about on OSX.

Note: this isn't a second login, this is more taking over the screen remotely. There's ways with VNC on some platforms to do a second login instead of taking over the screen, but not sure how to do that on OSX.

Comment: I don't know about Apple Remote Desktop but VNC is not exactly the same as a XDMCP request. With an XDMCP request you have your very own session.

Comment: Apple Remote Desktop is basically a cannibalized VNC.

Comment: @Ludwig: edited to make that clearer.
@Johannes: Yeah, pretty much, but with some features that are useful in many cases...

Comment: You're telling me something useful I didn't know about, but I'd like to login 2 times with different users and use the machine concurrently

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question over on ServerFault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/9681/remote-background-gui-login-to-osx-workstation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [howto.diveintomark.org](http://howto.diveintomark.org/download/HOWTO%20use%20your%20Mac%20from%20anywhere%20-%20desktop%20edition.mp4) which has a detailed tutorial. It's from the Windows perspective, but bases on putty and VNC which makes it flexible to UNIX as well.